# How to profile Domino Agents (AMgr) with YourKit?

Tags: java, profiling, lotus-domino, yourkit

Since I am having issues with a large Domino Agent, I wanted to be able to profile it. I've heard lots of lovely things about Yourkit, and followed the instructions in David Leedy's video:

http://notesin9.com/index.php/2012/11/29/notesin9-091-xpages-memory-profiling-part-1/

I have created a text file, YourKitOptionsFile.txt with the following line:

```
agentpath:C:\ProgramData\YourKit\yjpagent_13082_64_603ABE4D.dll=
disablestacktelemetry,disableexceptiontelemetry,delay=10000,listen=192.168.1.40:10001
```

and added this line to my notes.ini:

```
JavaOptionsFile=C:\Program Files\IBM\Domino\YourKitOptionsFile.txt
```

The Server is Domino 9.0.1 and the YourKit version is 2013 build 13082. OS is Windows 8.1 (can't afford Server license).

All the documentation I have found enables us to connect to the JVM run by nhttp.exe but I am interested in the JVMs with Amgr.exe.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look possible. I'm answering my own question with a resounding 'no'