# Profiling Domino / Notes JVM CPU and Memory

Tags: jvm, profiling, xpages, agents

I have scheduled Java Agents.  I would like to use a profiler to monitor the JVM to see how the server is performing.

When developing and testing, I run the agent from my Domino Designer from my workstation.

The workstation and server have a Java JRE installed.

Domino and Notes appears to have its own JVM directory.

Tools like VisualVM seem to connect to the computers JVM, how would I use something like VisualVM to monitor the JVM used to run xpages and agents?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882973/how-to-profile-domino-agents-amgr-with-yourkit) and my attempts many years ago I think you can't do it your way.

***Edited*** to reflect comments...

Anyway, I was able to profile XPages indirectly via [heap monitoring](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-memoryanalyzer/) or NSD dumps (that's the extreme - for freezing code).

For XPages, take a look at this project [XPages Toolbox](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=NHEF-84X8MU). For Java Agent, try native agent profiler:

http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tutorial/How-the-Agent-Profiler-tool-improves-Notes-Domino-performance

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_PROFILING_AGENTS_AND_WEB_SERVICES_STEPS.html

In worst case, try to [debug your agent](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DEBUGGING_JAVA_SERVER_AGENTS.html) to get a picture of collections it iterates or paths it goes in the code execution. Just be aware - remote debugger tends to attach to one of two JVMs - agent manager's or http's task. Be sure it [attaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100261/can-not-attach-debugger-to-http-jvm-amgr-jvm-is-attached-instead) to the right one.

Comment: I am aware of that one.  After some reading, there are some switches you can set for when the JVM starts to use JMX.  I have to figure out where to set these on a domino server so it can start up with this enabled.

Comment: This documentation shows a .jar profiler needs to be installed in the xsp directory. https://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/852fcfa76eb36baa85256bae00100855/A4320D679F9C73688625770A00725704/$File/XPagesToolbox.pdf  I wonder if it can be used by other tools, and does it set the JVM switches during run time into debug mode.

Comment: The profiler in the toolbox is actually different and only works for with HTTP process, basically for XPages/OSGi apps. It cannot currently be used with agents.